# Get refresh_token from hellojs

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, hello.js

I'm using [hello.js](https://github.com/MrSwitch/hello.js) to login users with social networks from the client. All works as expected, but now I see that I also need the `refresh_token`, because I have to use the client credentials from the server.

So, following the [docs](https://adodson.com/hello.js/#refresh-access-token):

> Unlike Implicit grant; Explicit grant may return the refresh_token.

And in the `login` method options:

> response_type: Implicit (token) or Explicit (code) Grant flow

So I added the option `response_type: 'code'` to the `init` method.

Also, I added the scope `offline_access` ([scope docs](https://adodson.com/hello.js/#scope) (last one)):

> Persist the tokens or acquire a Refresh Token for continued access

But now, when I try to login with any social network I get this error:

> "The client_id "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" is unknown"

This is weird, because the client_id is the right one, and removing this option it works as expected.

Am I missing anything, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this Explicit Grant flow your using requires a server-server handshake you need to have a server defined by the oauth_proxy setting for HelloJS to use in order to perform the handshake, the error your seeing is coming from the default proxy server //auth-server.herokuapp.com

See http://adodson.com/hello.js/#oauth-proxy for more info

Comment: Thank you. I also had to set the `force` option to true.